The cone generated by a finite set of points is a polyhedron

Prerequisites
A subset $K$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a cone if for every $x \in K$
and every $\lambda > 0$, $\lambda x \in K$. If $x_1,\dots, x_p$ are
points in $\mathbb{R}^n$, a conic combination of $x_1, \dots, x_p$
is $x = \sum_{j = 1}^p \lambda_j x_j$, where $\lambda_j \ge 0$ for
every $j = 1, \dots, p$. The conic hull of $X$ is defined as the
smallest cone containing $X$. It is simple to prove that the conic
hull coincides with the set of all conic combinations of elements
of $X$.
A polyhedron in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is the intersection of a finite
number of closed hyperplanes. A hyperplane in $\mathbb{R}^n$ can be
written as the set $$ H = \big\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n : \alpha^\mathsf{T}x \le \beta \big\} $$ where $\alpha$ is a vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and
$\beta$ is a real number. Thus, a polyhedron can be written in the
form $$ P = \big\{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n : Ax \le b \big\} $$ where $A$ is a $n\times p$
matrix and $b$ is a $p$-vector.
Prop. 1.
If $P$ is a polyhedral cone (i.e. a cone which is also a polyhedron),
there exists a matrix $Q$ such that $$ P = \big\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n : Qx \le 0 \big\} $$

I would like to prove the following result:
Lemma. The conic hull of a finite set of points $e_1, \dots, e_p$ is a polyhedron. In particular, there exists a matrix $Q$ such that $$ \operatorname{cone}\big(\{e_1,\dots,e_p\}\big) = \big\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n : Qx \le 0\big\}.$$
My attempt
The elements of $\operatorname{cone}(\{e_1,\dots,e_p\})$ are of the form $x = \sum_{j = 1}^p \lambda_i x_i$ where $\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_p \ge 0$. Thus set of all pairs $(x,\lambda) \in \mathbb{R}^{np}$ such that
$$
x = \sum_{j=1}^p \lambda_j x_j, \qquad \lambda \ge 0
$$
is a polyhedron in $\mathbb{R}^{np}$.
There is therefore a matrix $A$ such that this set can be written in the form
$$
\left\{ (x,\lambda) \in \mathbb{R}^{np} : x = \sum_{j=1}^p \lambda_j x_j,\lambda \ge 0 \right\} = \big\{(x, \lambda) \in \mathbb{R}^{np} : A(x,\lambda) \le b \big\}.
$$
Now, somehow it is said that therefore the cone is of the form $\{x : Qx \le 0\}$, but I am not quite sure how this is proved.
Also, isn't there a more abstract proof that uses geometric properties of convex sets (e.g. the separation theorems)? If anyone knows a better proof or is able to fix this one, can you please help me?
